# how can i store array to queue in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, queue

```
queue < int* > qq;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int cc[2] = {i, i + 1};
    qq.push(cc);
}
```

The N is large but not Exact so I want use queue.
I want to store many arrays to queue,but the arrays which qq stored are the same one.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code won't work. Each `cc` has the same stack location in the loop.

You need to allocate the `cc` array in the heap, perhaps using `int *cc = new int[2];` (but then you need to `delete` it later).

A better way would be to have `cc` declared as a `std::vector` or `std::array` or `std::tuple` (in C++11).

Comment: great. It works. thank you . but what's the difference ? It's between C and C++ ?

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is *syntactically* right, but *conceptually* wrong. You're inserting local array which gets created in each iteration and destroyed at the end of the iteration; that leaves `qq` in an unusable state. Outside the loop, dereferencing any element of `qq` would invoke undefined behavior.

Use `std::vector`:

```
std::queue<std::vector<int>> qq;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    std::vector<int> cc{i, i + 1};
    qq.push(cc);
}
```

Comment: Thank you . Maybe It's time to throw arrays away.

Answer (score 0):

You push each time the same address, namely, `cc`. You need to dedine a struct holding the two values, like so:

```
struct CC {
    int x, y;
    CC(int _x, int _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
}

queue<CC> qq;
```

and then..

```
qq.push(CC(i, i + 1));
```

Comment: struct is not very good ,in fact cc is a long arrays not just two member . thank you all the same .